# Error : failed to Retrieve data for this request when expanding subscriptions in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, replication

We are getting error when expanding subscriptions to delete them, we have already dropped distribution database. The error text is

> Failed to Retrieve data for this request. Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

[image]

Comment: This looks to be a case of orphaned replication. If you want to remove replication, run sp_removedbreplication on your subscriber database and it will remove replication. See after that if you are able top expand subscriptions folder.

Comment: I called this stored procedure on subscriber, but it completed with errors. I further called this stored procedure on publisher, and publishers were deleted. I am still getting same error when I am trying to expand subscription.

Comment: What errors did you get on subscriber when the SP was run? Also are you logged in to SQL Server with 'sa' privileges?